Nullhomotopy Lemma (Just for a small part)
I was reading the proof for null-homotopy lemma in Munkres's Topology book, and I cannot convince myself for the suggestion:

One can replace $S^2$ by the one-point compactification $\mathbb{R}^2 \cup \{\infty\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$, letting $a$ and $b$ correspond to the points $0$ and $\infty$.

Then I tried reprove the lemma by just assuming as if we just mapped $b$ to $\infty$.
This is where I struggled. Let $a \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and assume that $A$ is a compact space. Let $g(x): A \to (\mathbb{R}^2 - a)$ be a continuous mapping. Also suppose $a$ is in the unbounded component of $\mathbb{R}^2 - g(A)$. We know $\mathbb{R}^2 - g(A)$ is locally path connected. Now pick a point other than $a$ in the unbounded component of $\mathbb{R}^2 - g(A)$, and name it $p$. Since $a$ and $p$ live in the same component, there is path in $\mathbb{R}^2 - g(A)$, name it $\alpha$, that starts from $a$ and ends at $p$.
By this set up, define a homotopy $G(x,t): A \times I \to \mathbb{R}^2 - a$ by the equation:
$G(x,t) = g(x) - \alpha(t)$
The book says $G(x,t) \neq a$ since $\alpha$ does not intersect the set $g(A)$ but I cannot see this.
Can someone enlighten me?

It is no surprise that you cannot see this because it isn't necessarily true unless $a = 0$.
For a counterexample, let $A = *$ be a point, $g(A) = \{0\}$, $a = -1$ and $p = 1$ with $\alpha$ any path from $-1$ to $1$ not passing through 0. You then have $G(*, 1) = 0 - \alpha(1) = -1 = a$, whoops!
On the other hand that if $a = 0$, then $G(x, t) = 0$ is to say that $g(x) - \alpha(t) = 0$, i.e. $g(x) = \alpha(t)$ which is absurd as $\alpha$ does not intersect $g(A)$.
So there's one reason for the assumption $a = 0$, even though you can still make this work by choosing a different $G$ (I'll leave you to think about how one can use the $a = 0$ case together with translations to find a candidate).

Thank you so much... I had just figured it out at the same time you wrote the answer lol. I suppose choosing $G(x,t) = g(x) - \alpha (t) + a$ solves the issue. Thanks again!
